# Why does my form doesn't send file in iE8?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I'm doing a simple file form in php, it works with safari, mozilla(mac&pc) chrome(mac&pc) and NOT with IE8, my $_FILES is emplty!.

header :

```
<?php
session_start();
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP TAIa PSAa PSDa OUR IND UNI", policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml"');
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>mcp</title>

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=IE8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"  href="../styles/design.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"  href="../styles/style.css"/>
    <!--JS -->
    <script src="../js/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/parsley.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-pic">
        <img src="../styles/img/header_pic.png" alt="header-pic" />
    </div>
    <div id="mpcp">
        <img src="../styles/img/mpcp.png" alt="mpcp" />
    </div>
```

My form is there :

```
<form action="thanks.php" method="post"  data-validate="parsley" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="input-firstname">First name</label>
<input data-required="true" type="text" class="text" id="input-name-field" name="firstname"/><br>

<label for="input-lastname">Last name</label>
<input data-required="true" type="text" class="text" id="input-surname-field" name="lastname"/><br>

<label for="input-mail">e-mail</label>
<input data-type="email" data-required="true" type="text" class="text" id="input-mail-field" name="email"/><br>

<label for="input-picture">Picture</label>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Browse" />
<input type="text" id="filename" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="uploadme" />


    <input id="validate" type="submit" value="VALIDATE">
</form>
```

Process file code is there :

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['photo'] = $_POST['firstname'].'-'.$_POST['lastname'];




$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$_SESSION['photo'] = $_POST['firstname'].'-'.$_POST['lastname'].'.'.$extension;

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    } else {
        $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_POST['firstname'].'-'.$_POST['lastname'];
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            unlink("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
        $res = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].'.'.$extension);
        if ($res == true) {
            echo "Stored in: " . "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        } else {
            $error = "Invalid file";
        }
    }
} else {
    $error = "Invalid file";
}
} else {
    header("Location: reglement.php");
}
```

I'm about to punch my computer cause it always go to     header("Location: reglement.php");
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where's php-code which performs upload?

Comment: Do you close the `<form>` tag?

Comment: Yes i closed the form tag, just forgot to put it in the hurry..

Comment: I do not believe this simple form does not work in IE8, actually it has nothing to do with IE8+ until you use some HTML5. Would need whole HTML code.

Comment: i just added the header, believe it or not but it only doesn't work with ie